# Jquery file compress and upload in Chunks

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, compression, chunks

I've been trying to implement file compression and then uploading the compressed file in Chunks.

For File compression, I've used :

```
var maxWidth = 960, maxHeight = 960, imageWidth = image.width,
    imageHeight = image.height;

                if (imageWidth > imageHeight) {
                    if (imageWidth > maxWidth) {
                        imageHeight *= maxWidth / imageWidth;
                        imageWidth = maxWidth;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (imageHeight > maxHeight) {
                        imageWidth *= maxHeight / imageHeight;
                        imageHeight = maxHeight;
                    }
                }

                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                canvas.width = imageWidth;
                canvas.height = imageHeight;

                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);

                // The resized file ready for upload
                var finalFile = canvas.toDataURL(fileType);
```

and this is returning a base64 format.

But for File Uploading in Chunks, I've used some technique which is accepting only file but not base64 format :(

My Chunks uploading Code will be something like this :

```
cful = Object.create(chunkedFileUploader);
cful.init(item.file(), item.messageid(), '', item.messageid(), false, item.height, item.width);
//self.uploaderCollection.push(cful);
cful.uploadMetaData();
```

Is there any way to :

1) get a file instead of base64 after compressing
2) accept base64 for chunks Uploading.
3) or is there any other better way to do this with out these complexity?

Thanks in advance :)